How to draw crop marks over a CameraView
I am using CameraView from clr-namespace:BarcodeScanner.Mobile;assembly=BarcodeScanner.Mobile.Maui in order to read QR codes.
I want to draw crop marks in the corners of the detected QR code.In the CameraView_OnDetected event, OnDetectedEventArg parameter, I can get CornerPoints but, how can I use them to draw the crop marks?
